# MVC3: Create View populating data in object and in attribute object at same time

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, model

I'm pretty sure that this have been answered before, but i'm having trouble in finding anything that can help me. The problem is:

I have what would be a generic class and its specialization, like a PERSON and a CLIENT (which IS a PERSON). So, i have 2 tables on the database, which are:

```
PESSOA_FISICA
  ID_PESSOA_FISICA  Identity
  TX_NOME           Varchar(120)
  TX_CPF            Char(8)
  DT_NASCIMENTO     DateTime

CLIENTE_VAREJO
  ID_CLIENTE_VAREJO Identity
  ID_PESSOA_FISICA  Int      (FK to PESSOA_FISICA)
  IN_STATUS         Char(1)
  TX_FILIAL         Varchar(20)
```

For the C# classes, i got this:

```
[Table("PESSOA_FISICA")]
public class PessoaFisica
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID_PESSOA_FISICA")]
    public int? IDPessoaFisica { get; set; }

    [Column("TX_NOME")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Column("TX_CPF")]
    public string CPF { get; set; }

    [Column("DT_NASCIMENTO")]
    public DateTime Nascimento { get; set; }
}

[Table("CLIENTE_VAREJO")]
public class ClienteVarejo
{
    [Key]
    [Column("ID_CLIENTE_VAREJO")]
    public int? IDClienteVarejo {get;set;}

    [Column("ID_PESSOA_FISICA")]
    [ForeignKey("PessoaFisica")]
    public int IDPessoaFisica { get; set; }

    public virtual PessoaFisica PessoaFisica { get; set; }

    [Column("IN_STATUS")]
    public String Status { get; set; }

    [Column("TX_FILIAL")]
    public String Filial { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is... I just don't know how to create a CREATE view that can accept data into the ClienteVarejo model, but also into the PessoaFisica at the same time (because, whenever i'll be entering data for a new ClienteVarejo, i'll have to be entering data for a new PessoaFisica as well).

I've already realized that, in a View strongly typed as ClienteVarejo, i could use Razor syntax like:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PessoaFisica.Nome)
```

But in my case (which is: in the creation of both objects at same time), how to make the model validation occur to both objects?

Thanks for any help that you can give me... :)

Marcelo Myara
Rio de Janeiro, Brazil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use the Domain model for your view. Create a new ***POCO*** class which is specific for your view. Let's call it **ViewModel**.

```
public class CreateClientVM
{
  [Required]
  public string ClientName { set;get;}
  [Required]
  public string ContactPersonName { set;get;}

  //other properties here as needed
}
```

Now in yout `GET` action create an object of this class and pass to the `View` method.

```
public ActionResult CreateClient()
{
  var vm=new CreateClientVM();
  return View(vm);
}
```

Make your view strongly typed to the ViewModel class.

```
@model CreateClientVM
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.ClientName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ClientName)

  @Html.LabelFor(x=>x.ContactPersonName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ContactPersonName)

  <input type="submit" />
}
```

When user submit the form, read the values from view model and assign it to an object of your domain modal and save. Thanks to MVC model binding. :)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateClient(CreateClientVM model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var domainModelClient=new ClienteVarejo();
    domainModelClient.Name=model.ClientName;
    domainModelClient.ContactPerson=new ContactPerson();
    domainModelClient.ContactPerson.Name=model.ContactPersonName;

    yourRepositary.SaveClient(domainModelClient);  
    //If saved successfully, Redirect to another view (PRG pattern)
    return RedirectToAction("ClientSaved");
  }
  return View(model);    
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Shyju, thanks for the help. This will do, for sure! :D  My only remaining concern is that in using POCO classes for everyone of this situations i'll probably end up with twice the number of classes (one for the real model and other to serve to the viewing of those models). But, at least it is an easy and clear solution. Thanks a lot!! :D